# NSArray with multiple properties to populate a uipickerview

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

That's my problem:
I have an NSMutableArray called `arrayLingue` that contains 3 properties:

- nomeStato
- nomeLingua
- Codice

I'd like to populate an `UIPickerView` with a `nomeStato` property.
How to do that?

This my code:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
        return [arrayLingue count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1; 
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{    
    return [arrayLingue objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    Lingua *lingua =[self.arrayLingue objectAtIndex:row];

    self.labelA.text=lingua.nomeStato;
    self.labelB.text=lingua.Codice;
    self.labelC.text=lingua.nomeLingua;
    return;
}
```

I know the problem is in `titleforrow` because I have multiple properties. 
But I don't know how to select/say to XCode to take only one property. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same as what you are doing in the `didSelectRow:...` method:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    Lingua *lingua = self.arrayLingue[row];

    return lingua.nomeStato;
}
```